# intellij idea duplicated classes in Libraries

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have Project where is included several modules.
each module has its own build.gradle file, where is dependencies for it's module.
my main problem:
for example i have module-one and module-two, each of them has it own build.gradle where is same .jar libraries but different versions.

when building application, into each modules Library are both dependency classes both versions and getting error because of application trying to call function(from version 1.1)   but i need from version 1.2

please explain how can i fix it, to don't mix up Libraries within modules.

Comment: I have same problems. Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried manually edit dependencies for modules? (Project Settings > Modules > select a module > Dependencies).